# How to make a list as a key of dict in Python?

Tags: c++, python, hash

In C++, I will wirte `map<vector<int>,int> mv;`
But in Python,I get a error of "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"
I guess maybe in C++,map is a red-black tree ,but in Python,the dict is a hash table.
But how can I do the same thing like above in Python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't need to resize the key, a [`tuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) would probably be the most efficient way to go about it:

```
mv = {}
mv[(1, 2, 3)] = 456
```

Comment: @kamushin - All of the entries in a tuple must also be hashable in order for the tuple to be hashable - you could do a tuple of tuples, but a tuple of lists would have the same issues as a list.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use list as dictionary key because it is not hashable.

```
>>> mv = {}
>>> mv[[1,2,3]] = 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Use tuple instead.

```
>>> mv[(1,2,3)] = 2
>>> mv
{(1, 2, 3): 2}
```